# Variable containing single quotes just disappears

Tags: python, bash, pip

I have a script that drives installation of a lot of packages.  In one place, it uses pip.  One of the packages requires it's own special command-line argument for the build process.

pip enables install options to be passed in to the build process as follows:

pip install -U --timeout 30 $options --install-option='--hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5' tables

--install-option is an argument to pip.  The value it is set to, --hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5, will be passed on to the build process. So, the single quotes have to be there to group all of the text as one argument that follows the equal sign.  You might say I could just use double quotes to surround the value of the install-option.  Well, at the command line I could.

But, here is the added complication.  This is in a script.  The parameter values for the pip command are passed to a function in an array.  The array entry for this package looks like:
("tables,pip,,--install-option='--hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5'")

The receiving function parses the array entry with set as in this fragment:

```
IFS=","  # to split apart the pkg array entries

for pkg in "${pkglist[@]}"; do
    set -- ${pkg} 
    if [[ "$2" == "pip" ]]; then  # $1 is pkg, $2 is pip, $3 is url, $4 is options
        DoPip $1 $3 $4
    ...
```

So, DoPip, for this package, is seeing:  DoPip tables '' --install-option='--hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5'

The problem occurs in DoPip.  I can't figure out how to expand the last argument when I need to run pip itself.  I have done a bunch of debugging to see what happens.  What happens is that the value of $3 is simply being dropped--it just disappears.  It will echo in a string, but it will not work as part of a command.

Looking at the function DoPip.  To help debug, I reassign the arguments to explicit variables.  It's not necessary, but helped make sure there weren't  stupid mistakes on my part.

```
DoPip() {

 # run pip command to install packages
    # arguments: 1: package-name 2: optional source <URL>
    #            3: optional pip options
    pkgname=$1
    url=$2
    options=$3
```

Next, I set a variable source to be either the pkgname or the url, if the url is non-blank.  I am skipping this fragment--it works.

To debug, I echo the reassigned arguments:

```
echo "1. The inbound arguments are: $pkgname $url $options"
```

The output LOOKS like it ought to work:

1. The inbound arguments are: tables --install-option='--hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5'

Here is the statement that actually runs pip with these arguments:

```
 pip install -U --timeout 30 $options $source
```

With debugging on, here is what Bash actually sees and runs:

```
+ pip install -U --timeout 30 tables
```

Whoa!  What happened to $options?  It's GONE!  In fact, immediately prior to this statement I repeat the echo to verify that no intervening part of the script caused the value to get flushed.  Not a problem.  I can echo the value of $options immediately prior--it's ok.  Then, it's gone.

I can't figure out what is happening or how to do this.  I have tried various ways of escaping the single quotes in the array where the string literal is originally created based on reading how very special single quotes are.  Nothing works.  The whole variable expansion just goes away.

I have tried doing the expansion in various ways:

```
pip install -U --timeout 30 "$options" $source
```

That doesn't work.  The string in options appears but surrounded by single quotes so the pip command throws an error.  Next, I tried:

```
pip install -=U --timeout 30 "${options}" $source
```

also fails:  single quotes and the curly braces appear and pip is unhappy again.

The --install-options argument is essential.  The build fails without it.

There has to be some way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer for the python package tables (aka, potables) finds the hdf5 libraries either with a build switch supplied to pip or by setting an environment variable before starting the build.  It was easier/more reliable in the bash script to simply create the environment variable immediately before starting to build tables.  There is no need to put it in bash_profile.  The environment variable only needs to exist in the shell where tables is built.  Once tables is installed, there is no further need for the environment variable.

In this code fragment, pkglist is an array of modules to be installed and InstallPackages is a function that walks the array and calls the appropriate installer:  pip in this case.

```
    if [[ "$hdf5exists" == "True" ]]; then
        # assert hdf libraries installed
        export HDF5_DIR=/usr/local/hdf5
        pkglist=("${hdf5_pkglist[@]}")  # only install Python wrappers for hdf5
        InstallPackages
    fi
```

So, this is the solution I adopted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

This script gave the following output:

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
options=--install-option='--hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5'
source=tables
pip install -U --timeout 30 $options $source


$ ./script.sh 
#!/bin/bash -vx
options=--install-option='--hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5'
+ options=--install-option=--hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5
source=tables
+ source=tables
pip install -U --timeout 30 $options $source
+ pip install -U --timeout 30 --install-option=--hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5 tables
Downloading/unpacking tables
  Downloading tables-3.1.1.tar.gz (6.7MB): 6.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_ankur/tables/setup.py) egg_info for package tables
    * Using Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35)
    * Found numpy 1.6.1 package installed.
    .. ERROR:: You need numexpr 2.0.0 or greater to run PyTables!
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    * Using Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35)

* Found numpy 1.6.1 package installed.

.. ERROR:: You need numexpr 2.0.0 or greater to run PyTables!

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ankur/tables
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ankur/.pip/pip.log
```

Ignore the errors, I am seeing the value of $options being correctly read and passed to the shell.

Comment: Thanks.  It should be that simple but it's not.  Could it be that I have IFS="," to pull apart the array entry into arguments?   I can't even do echo $options >> returns as a blank line.  But, echo "some text $source $options" works.  I am completely flummoxed.  Have wasted hours!

Comment: Adding much more weirdness to this.  I must have 3 variable expansions in succession for $options to expand.  echo "some text $source $options" won't work.  echo "some text $source $url $options" does work.  Whoa!

Comment: To make this weirder yet, the order of expansion in echo statements is ignored!  echo "1. The inbound arguments are: $options $pkgname $url"  and echo "2. The inbound arguments are: $pkgname $url $options" both produce output with $pkgname appearing first and then $option.  Note that $url has value of empty string in both cases.   This is just getting crazy.

Comment: The fact that the order of output for the two echo statements told me something.  I looked at the inbound arguments passed by the two functions.  Bash doesn't "see" blank arguments--they aren't there.  So, the actual options string was going into the $url variable.  I still have some issues with how to have a blank string as an argument because of using the array to pass the 4 segments.  But, it is not a bash variable expansion problem any more.

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere.  Solved the array problem:  a blank entry is set to none.  The receiving function gets an arg valued none and I test for it.  Ugly, but clear enough.  However, still have a variable expansion problem because of single quotes.  here is the offending script line (from set -x):  pip install -U --timeout 30 '--install-option='\''--hdf5=/usr/local/hdf5'\''' tables   Note that the entire install-option is single quoted to enable escaping the embedded quotes.  pip doesn't like that.

Comment: I am just at my wit's end.  There must be something with either IFS or the fact that I am passing in the parameters to a function and not assigning them at command line as in abc's answer.  I can't get the $options variable to expand without being surrounded by single quotes.  Cannot have those single quotes--must just be text to be a valid input argument to pip.  **Any solutions?**

Comment: @LewisLevin If you don't want quotes in the output, don't put them into the input. Why do you expect them to disappear? (And, by the way, the simpler solution to your blank arguments problem is: `DoPip "$1" "$3" "$4"`)

Comment: Just to eliminate all of the confusion and isolate the actual problem. When $option is expanded as an argument to the pip command it is surrounded by single quotes. pip will not accept the single quotes. I've seen this before and had to hard code the arguments (in a case where I could).  The goal is to get the variable expansion to occur without single quotes surrounding it. The problem is the value of the variable includes single quotes.

Comment: @LewisLevin: You're operating under a misapprehension about how quotes work, which is the source of your confusion. Don't put apostrophes into the argument. You don't need them and I don't know why you think you do need them.

Comment: @rici:   The quotes around the sub-argument are shown in the potables docs (but not around the entire argument).  Yes, I started with DoPip "$1" "$3" "$4" but used the named variables to clear up what was going on.  The caller uses slightly different ordering of the arguments (yeah, bad...).  I will try the thing without the inner quotes even though I revised the whole mess.  Yup, it sure works.

Answer (score 0):

All of this was embedded in a very large script.  I created a shorter version to focus on the problem.  In the end, I adopted a different approach relying on the environment variable HDF5_DIR rather than the cmd line switch for pip.

Apparently, you can only do one or the other.  In any case, in the cleaned up code the argument was passed, but that is an error if the environment variable is present.  Go figure.

I have the shorter code if anyone is interested.

When banging head too hard, step away from the wall and find another approach. I'll call this one closed.

Comment: You should post your solution here and accept it as the answer.